# MySQL GROUP_CONCAT inside GROUP_CONCAT

Tags: mysql

I am not very good with MySQL and I am trying to figure how to build a specific query.

I pretty sure I need to use GROUP_CONCAT inside another GROUP_CONCAT but I can't figure out the right syntax in this specific situation.

Here is a simplified version of the 3 tables I need to get values from :

```
====================================
TABLE NAME : models

ModelID     ModelName    Year
------------------------------------
100         Mazda3       2015
101         Mazda3       2016

====================================


====================================
TABLE NAME : styles

ModelID     StyleID    Trim
----------------------------
100         200        GS
100         201        GX  
100         202        GT 
101         300        GS
101         301        GX
101         302        GT     

====================================


====================================
TABLE NAME : colors

ModelID     StyleID    GenericExtColor
--------------------------------------
100         200        Red
100         200        Blue  
100         201        Red 
100         201        Blue
100         202        Red
100         202        Blue  
101         300        Red
101         300        Blue  
101         301        Red 
101         301        Blue
101         302        Red
101         302        Blue  

====================================
```

What I would like the output to look like (html list) :

```
Mazda3 2015
----- GS
----------- Red
----------- Blue
----- GX
----------- Red
----------- Blue
----- GT
----------- Red
----------- Blue

Mazda3 2016
----- GS
----------- Red
----------- Blue
----- GX
----------- Red
----------- Blue
----- GT
----------- Red
----------- Blue
```

Here is the query I use at the moment (only 2 levels (Model / Trim) since I don't know how to get the the 3rd layer (colors))

```
SELECT models.ModelID, models.ModelName, models.ModelYear,
GROUP_CONCAT(styles.Trim) AS trims
FROM models, styles
WHERE 
  models.ModelName LIKE '%Mazda3%' AND 
  styles.ModelID = models.ModelID
GROUP BY models.ModelID
```

The PHP I use to render the result of my query :

```
<ul>
  while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { 

    $trims = explode(",", $row['trims']);

    echo '<li>'.$row['ModelID'].'</li>';
    echo '<ul>';

      echo '<li>'.$row['ModelName'].'</li>';
      echo '<li>'.$row['ModelYear'].'</li>';

      echo '<ul>';
        foreach ($trims as $trim) {
          echo '<li>'.$trim.'</li>';
        }
      echo '</ul>';

    echo '</ul>';
  }
</ul>
```

I can provide more informations if needed. Any help would be very appreciated!
Thank you

Comment: Just a short idea: I would not use `group_concat` here. `join` all 3 tables, order them by the 3 column attributes. Then create the menu in php directly from these rows: you have 3 nested while loops; a while-loop at depth n ends when any of the first n-1 columns of a row changed from the row before.

Comment: @Solarflare This sounds like a good idea but like I said, I am not really good with MySQL, do you have a short example of what the query / php should look like? Which type of JOIN should I use? I am not asking for the complete query and code but just a little guideline would immensely help me.  Thank you very much